# Multiple rows in to single row in SQL Server if each column has only one value per employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to do this please help.

I have the following data. This is a data sample for week. I want  single row per **EmployeeName** / **CrewID** (unless there are 2 values for a Employee in a single date).

If **ORIGINAL DATA** is like this :

```
2018-08-05   2018-08-06   2018-08-07   2018-08-08   2018-08-09   2018-08-10   2018-08-11   CrewID    EmployeeName   
 ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ -------- ---------------- 
  NULL         174          173          172          171          NULL         NULL              9   Kanhaiya        
  NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         178          NULL              9   Kanhaiya        
  NULL         174          173          172          171          NULL         NULL              8   Santanu Maulik  
  NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         178          NULL              8   Santanu Maulik
```

The **OUTPUT** of the above original should be in single row per person as below.

```
    2018-08-05   2018-08-06   2018-08-07   2018-08-08   2018-08-09   2018-08-10   2018-08-11   CrewID    EmployeeName   
 ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ -------- ---------------- 
  NULL         174          173          172          171          178          NULL              9   Kanhaiya  
  NULL         174          173          172          171          178          NULL              8   Santanu Maulik
```

but still the data may be spitted in multiple rows per employee for certain condition like if the employee has multiple values for a single date  eg. '2018-08-10'

If **ORIGINAL DATA** is like this :

```
  2018-08-05   2018-08-06   2018-08-07   2018-08-08   2018-08-09   2018-08-10   2018-08-11   CrewID   EmployeeName  
 ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ -------- -------------- 
  NULL         174          173          172           171         NULL         NULL              9   Kanhaiya      
  NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL          163         178          NULL              9   Kanhaiya
```

The **OUTPUT** of the above original data  should be like below.

```
  2018-08-05   2018-08-06   2018-08-07   2018-08-08   2018-08-09   2018-08-10   2018-08-11   CrewID   EmployeeName  
 ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ -------- -------------- 
  NULL         174          173          172          171          178           NULL              9   Kanhaiya      
  NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         163          NULL          NULL              9   Kanhaiya
```

I have managed to get the data with a stored procedure.

This is the main logic section of the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDataForCustomWeekViewReport]
    @Week AS INT, 
    @typeOfData AS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @weekAdjustAdd INT

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET DATEFIRST 7;
    SET @weekAdjustAdd = (@Week - 1) * 7

    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    ----------------------------- 
    -- Get unique values of pivot column  

    SELECT   
        @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(WORKDAYS)
    FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT WORKDAYS 
         FROM  
             (SELECT 
                  DATEADD(DAY, @weekAdjustAdd, CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7, -1) AS date)) AS WORKDAYS 
              UNION
              SELECT 
                  DATEADD(DAY, @weekAdjustAdd, CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7, 0) AS date)) AS WORKDAYS 
              UNION
              SELECT 
                  DATEADD(DAY, @weekAdjustAdd, CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7, 1) AS date)) AS WORKDAYS 
              UNION
              SELECT 
                  DATEADD(DAY, @weekAdjustAdd, CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,  DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7, 2) AS date)) AS WORKDAYS 
              UNION
              SELECT 
                  DATEADD(DAY, @weekAdjustAdd, CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7, 3) AS date)) AS WORKDAYS 
              UNION
              SELECT 
                   DATEADD(DAY, @weekAdjustAdd, CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,  DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7, 4) AS date)) AS WORKDAYS 
              UNION
              SELECT 
                  DATEADD(DAY, @weekAdjustAdd, CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7, 5) AS date)) AS WORKDAYS 
            ) i) AS PivotExample

  IF (@typeOfData = 'f')
  BEGIN   
 --Get unique values of pivot column   

--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
 --',JOBID, JobInfo,CrewID, EmployeeName,Color
  -- ,JI.INumber + '' - '' + JI.ITitle AS JobInfo, M.Color,
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N'
    DECLARE @Week AS int
    DECLARE @weekAdjustAdd int
    SET @Week=1
    SET DATEFIRST 7;
    SET @weekAdjustAdd = (@Week - 1) * 7 
    SELECT ' +   @PivotColumns + ', CrewID, EmployeeName
   FROM (


SELECT J.ID AS JOBID, C.ID AS CrewID ,c.CrewName AS EmployeeName ,  JI.ID AS JOBINSTANCE_ID,JI.WORKDAYS 

    FROM  [dbo].[Job] J 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Job_Instances] JI ON J.ID=JI.JOBID
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Instance_Employee_Relation] IER ON JI.ID=IER.JobInstanceID 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Crew] C  ON C.Id = IER.EMPLOYEEID 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Manager] M  ON M.Id = JI.ManagerID
    INNER JOIN dbo.JobType JT ON JT.ID = JI.JobTypeID
    WHERE   ( C.EmployeeTypeID=1 OR C.EmployeeTypeID IS NULL) AND JI.TYPE = ''F'' AND JI.WORKDAYS BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20) ,@weekAdjustAdd)+', CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7, -1) AS date)) AND DATEADD(DAY,'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(20) ,@weekAdjustAdd)+', CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7, 5) AS date)) 
)i 
 PIVOT( SUM(JobInstance_ID) 
    FOR [WORKDAYS] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P ORDER BY CASE WHEN EmployeeName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, EmployeeName'


--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery




  END
```

Here is the main schema section for the related tables.
[image: Here is the main schema section for the related tables.]

***UPDATE***

@Ven tried to help me out & did a good job but his answer is working if i have only 2 rows per employee but if i have more than 2 rows per employee his solution is not working.

**Original Data**

```
2018-08-05   2018-08-06   2018-08-07   2018-08-08   2018-08-09   2018-08-10   2018-08-11   CrewID    EmployeeName   
 ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ -------- ---------------- 
  NULL         174          173          172          171          NULL         NULL              9   Kanhaiya        
  NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         178          NULL              9   Kanhaiya        
  NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         183          182          NULL              8   Santanu Maulik  
  NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         178          NULL              8   Santanu Maulik  
  NULL         174          173          172          171          NULL         NULL              8   Santanu Maulik
```

**Output with @Ven's Solution** (did not work For CrewID 8 as he has 3 Rows but worked for CrewID 9 as he has 2 Rows.)

```
  CrewID    EmployeeName    2018-08-05   2018-08-06   2018-08-07   2018-08-08   2018-08-09   2018-08-10   2018-08-11  
 -------- ---------------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ 
       8   Santanu Maulik   NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         178          NULL        
       8   Santanu Maulik   NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         183          182          NULL        
       8   Santanu Maulik   NULL         174          173          172          171          NULL         NULL        
       9   Kanhaiya         NULL         174          173          172          171          178          NULL
```

Comment: You question is still not clear, i guess last table is your expected output ?. have you made any effort, please let us know.

Comment: @Ven yes last table is expected output for 3rd table. for 1st table the expected output is 2nd table.
means both condition should support.

Comment: first table is the original data ? you have date in column ? Can you please post your schema, sample data

Comment: Please provide some of your existing queries

Comment: @squirral 1st table & 3rd table could be 2 example of original data...
this is the data i have managed to get from a big dynamic query with pivoting . i can store this in a temp table & archive further requirements as i want if i get any help from here.

Comment: Edited... given main logic of my stored procedure.. but its hard to describe full schema here for table so i just gave the requirements.The data i can store to a temp table & then work on that if i get some help to achieve the output .

Comment: If the crew member has only one value per column as seen in your first example you can use MAX(column_name) and group on CrewID to get one row for each crew. It may be a good start but it won't work for your second case when a member has several values in one column

Comment: @holder Thanks for your suggestion but i need both case to work. BTW for Max it will only get the maximum value. what about the other data. i need all the data. the output i have made till now with the following sp is correct for now. but what i want is the requirement for my further progress.

Comment: I hope some SQL Server experts will help me out though i don't know if i am able to explain my question clearly or not.

Comment: @SantanuMaulik whats the logic in second case, there should be identity column apart from `crewid`,can all rows get value from first or second row where value is null

Comment: @Ven there can be a _JOBID_ added FROM JOB TABLE but i have not included it as i dont need job ID & JOB ID will be different in each row according to my query.In example the 2nd row & 1st row  has different JOBID ,but my requirements is i need data irrespective of job id if any date column value is null i can take data from 2nd row for that blank date column. Is the question clear to you now?

Comment: @SantanuMaulik `if any date coulmn value is null i can take data from 2nd row for that blank date column.` would u take it vice versa ?, in second case would u take data from first row if second row is null and a distinct would result is second column like `9 Kanhaiya NULL 174 173 172 163 178 NULL` and first row will be `9 Kanhaiya NULL 174 173 172 171 178 NULL`

Comment: @Ven no! my requirement is if 1st row has any date column null check for same date column for that user in 2nd 3rd and so one if it has. So if 1st row contains data from 2nd row then we don't need the 2nd row anymore . just remove 2nd row if 1st row has already the date value from 2nd row else keep 2nd row if any date column is not in 1st row. i can not keep duplicate data or cant remove data. i need all data in in one row or multiple row but if 1st row has any date column blank then 2nd row cant contain  value in that same date column rather move that value in same date column of 1st row.

Comment: @Ven got my point or still i am not able to clear my requirements?

Comment: @Ven  
 Already i have given the output i want for 2nd case.

Comment: @SantanuMaulik You are now very clear with your requirements, give me few minutes

Comment: @Ven Thanks for your time.

Comment: consider using `row_number()` and join according to the generated numbers

Comment: @RadimBača it would be great if you could answer this with example. what do you mean by join here & join with what?

Comment: @SantanuMaulik what version SQL you are using 2012 and above ?

Comment: @Ven sql server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Work this out in 3 different steps to satisfy requirements. There is no other dirty way of doing this :)

1) Get previous row and next row in table by self join (left join)

2) Case expression to get value from next row where value is null in first row and non-null 
   in second row

2) case  Expression if both rows are equal then null value in second row

```
  DECLARE @table TABLE (
    id INT identity(1, 1)
    ,[2018-08-05] INT
    ,[2018-08-06] INT
    ,[2018-08-07] INT
    ,[2018-08-08] INT
    ,[2018-08-09] INT
    ,[2018-08-10] INT
    ,[2018-08-11] INT
    ,CrewID INT
    ,EmployeeName VARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT @table
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ -------- ---------------- 
SELECT NULL
    ,174
    ,173
    ,172
    ,171
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,9
    ,'Kanhaiya'

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,163
    ,178
    ,NULL
    ,9
    ,'Kanhaiya'

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL
    ,174
    ,173
    ,172
    ,171
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,8
    ,'Santanu Maulik'

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,178
    ,NULL
    ,8
    ,'Santanu Maulik';
```

Script:

```
 WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY p.crewid ORDER BY p.crewID
                )
            ,p.*
        FROM @table p
        )
        ,ct2
    AS (
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT cte.CrewID
            ,cte.employeename
            ,CASE WHEN cte.[2018-08-05] IS NULL THEN nex.[2018-08-05] ELSE cte.[2018-08-05] END [2018-08-05]
            ,CASE WHEN cte.[2018-08-06] IS NULL THEN nex.[2018-08-06] ELSE cte.[2018-08-06] END [2018-08-06]
            ,CASE WHEN cte.[2018-08-07] IS NULL THEN nex.[2018-08-07] ELSE cte.[2018-08-07] END [2018-08-07]
            ,CASE WHEN cte.[2018-08-08] IS NULL THEN nex.[2018-08-08] ELSE cte.[2018-08-08] END [2018-08-08]
            ,CASE WHEN cte.[2018-08-09] IS NULL THEN nex.[2018-08-09] ELSE cte.[2018-08-09] END [2018-08-09]
            ,CASE WHEN cte.[2018-08-10] IS NULL THEN nex.[2018-08-10] ELSE cte.[2018-08-10] END [2018-08-10]
            ,CASE WHEN cte.[2018-08-11] IS NULL THEN nex.[2018-08-11] ELSE cte.[2018-08-11] END [2018-08-11]
        FROM CTE
        LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
        LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
        ORDER BY cte.CrewID
        )
        ,ct3
    AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT CrewID
            ,EmployeeName
            ,CASE WHEN [2018-08-05] = LEAD([2018-08-05]) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY crewid ORDER BY [2018-08-05]
                        ) THEN NULL ELSE [2018-08-05] END [2018-08-05]
            ,CASE WHEN [2018-08-06] = LEAD([2018-08-06]) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY crewid ORDER BY [2018-08-06]
                        ) THEN NULL ELSE [2018-08-06] END [2018-08-06]
            ,CASE WHEN [2018-08-07] = LEAD([2018-08-07]) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY crewid ORDER BY [2018-08-07]
                        ) THEN NULL ELSE [2018-08-07] END [2018-08-07]
            ,CASE WHEN [2018-08-08] = LEAD([2018-08-08]) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY crewid ORDER BY [2018-08-08]
                        ) THEN NULL ELSE [2018-08-08] END [2018-08-08]
            ,CASE WHEN [2018-08-09] = LEAD([2018-08-09]) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY crewid ORDER BY [2018-08-09]
                        ) THEN NULL ELSE [2018-08-09] END [2018-08-09]
            ,CASE WHEN [2018-08-10] = LEAD([2018-08-10]) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY crewid ORDER BY [2018-08-10]
                        ) THEN NULL ELSE [2018-08-10] END [2018-08-10]
            ,CASE WHEN [2018-08-11] = LEAD([2018-08-11]) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY crewid ORDER BY [2018-08-11]
                        ) THEN NULL ELSE [2018-08-11] END [2018-08-11]
        FROM ct2
        )
    SELECT *
    FROM ct3
    WHERE isnull([2018-08-05], 0) + isnull([2018-08-06], 0) + isnull([2018-08-07], 0) + isnull([2018-08-08], 0) + isnull([2018-08-09], 0) + isnull([2018-08-10], 0) + isnull([2018-08-11], 0) > 0
```

Comment: Ok let me try & will it work if there are more than 2 rows?

Comment: There may be n number of rows in my actual data . My example was only with 2 rows.

Comment: I am trying to implement your answer in my Stored Procedure. it will take time as my columns are all dynamic column. i have to store my current queried data to temp table & then will do apply your answer over that. Wll let you know Once its done. Thanks.

Comment: Its working only for 2 rows. if i have more than 2 rows per Employee its not working.